# Elixir Decode JSON List into Struct

Tags: json, struct, elixir, ecto, elixir-poison

I am using Elixir to retrieve a json from an external API and store it in a Postgresql database. I am using Poison to decode the json into Elixir Ecto (2.0) schemas. It is working well except for one aspect: an element of the json is a List without any keys. I am at a loss for how to map this element to an Elixir struct.

The json:

```
{"name": "Joe Random"
 "address": {
   "street": "123 Main St",
   "city": "Smalltown"
   },
 "interests": [
   "Biking",
   "Movies"
   ]
}
```

This json takes the form of a struct (person) with an embedded struct (address) and an embedded list (interests). I want to model this structure with Ecto.Schemas so I can load the json into it. The person and address structs are simple:

```
defmodule Person do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "person" do
    field :name, :string
    embeds_one :address, Address
  end
end

defmodule Address do
  use Ecto.Schema

  embedded_schema do
    field :street, :string
    field :city, :string
  end
end
```

I can use Poison.decode to load these structs:

```
Poison.decode!(json, as person: %Person{address: %Address{}})
```

However, how do I model and store the "interests": from the json? It's just a simple single-value list without any keys. Can I turn it into a map that I can then model with Ecto.Schema? Has anyone encountered an issue like this before?

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you want `field :interests, {:array, :string}` in `Person`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you, Dogbert. I added a field of type {:array, :string} for the "interests" element of the json to the Person Ecto.schema. I successfully loaded the struct from the json using Poison!

```
defmodule Person do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "person" do
    fields :name, :string
    embeds_one :address, Address
    fields :interests, {:array, :string}
  end
end
```